# how to call a method that is out of the class and pass the class instance to it in python django

Tags: python, django, django-models, slugify

I have a model named Klass with below code:

```
class Klass(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='class name')
slug = models.SlugField(default=slug_generator, allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
```

and it's the `slug_generator` function that is out of the class.

```
def slug_generator(instance, new_slug):
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    else:
        slug = slugify(instance.title)

    Klass = instance.__class__
    qs_exists = Klass.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
    if qs_exists:
        new_slug = "{slug}-{randstr}".format(
            slug=slug,
            randstr=random.randint(100000,999999)
        )
        return unique_slug_generator(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug
```

in order to creating unique slugs, I want to use this function.
i want to use this function for some other models.
how can i pass the class to it?

Comment: Why not define the `__init__` constructor and apply a unique ID generator in there along with any other instance properties you want?

Comment: @marchWest as i said, i want to use a function for some models, because i have 6 models that need unique slug according to their title properties. i don't want to write a code 6 times!

Comment: @MojtabaSalehiyan You can create an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) with common methods and inherit your models from this base class. You won't have to write the code 6 times.

Comment: In any case, a default value cannot depend on other data in the instance; apart from anything else, there *isn't* any other instance data at the point that the default is applied. Do this in the `save` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a abstract class that the other class hierachy from it, I don't check the code, but it is something like that

```
class Slug(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def slug_generator(instance, new_slug):
       if new_slug is not None:
       ....
```

and then:

```
class Klass(Slug):
.....
```